# OCR on antialiased text

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I have to OCR table from PDF document. I wrote simple Python+opencv script to get individual cells. After that new problem arose. Text is antialiased and not good-quality. 
Recognition rate of tesseract is very low. I've tried to preprocess images with adaptive thresholding but results weren't much better.
I've tried trial version of ABBYY FineReader and indeed it gives fine output, but I don't want to use non-free software.
I wonder if some preprocessing would solve issue or is it nessesary to write and learn other OCR system.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look closely at your antialiased text samples, you'll notice that the edges contain a lot of red and blue:

[image: enlarged view of antialiased text]

This suggests that the antialiasing is taking place inside your computer, which has used [subpixel rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) to optimise the results for your LCD monitor.

If so, it should be quite easy to extract the text at a higher resolution. For example, you can use ImageMagick to extract images from PDF files at 300 dpi by using a command line like the following:

```
convert -density 300 source.pdf output.png
```

You could even try loading the PDF in your favourite viewer and copying the text directly to the clipboard.

---

**Addendum:**

I tried converting your sample text back into its original pixels and applying the scaling technique mentioned in the comments. Here are the results:

Original image:
[image: original image]

After scaling 300% and applying simple threshold:
[image: scaled and thresholded image]

After smart scaling and thresholding:
[image: smart scaled and thresholded image]

As you can see, some of the letters are still a bit malformed, but I think there's a better chance of reading this with Tesseract.

Comment: Thanks about sugesting subpixel rendering, but text seems to be pre-rendered. Images I've attached were extracted using ImageMagic with -density 300. So it is not surprise that when I load page in PDF reader and magnify it, result is similiar.

Comment: @user3318776 I was playing around with this problem yesterday and came up with [an image scaling technique that takes sub-pixel antialiasing into consideration](http://ruletheweb.co.uk/blog/2014/02/subpixel-aware-image-scaling/). This might make it easier for Tesseract to extract the text from these scans. First you'll have to extract the original embedded images from your PDF file, but this shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Thanks. Accuracy is much better. I will try to retrain tesseract with text generated like that and compare results.