# How to get the accurate result for small font size

Tags: ocr, tesseract, tess4j

I am trying to use Tesseract 3.02 to read the text from application for validation purpose(automation testing). It always gives me incorrect result if the font size is small (8 to 10). I followed the below metioned image processing before passing the image to tesseract. 
1. Converted image to GrayScale. (Image format JPG)
2. Re-scaled image
3. Converted image to 300 DPI

After preprocessing the image, passed it to tesseract. Most of the Application images which I have are having small font size. Also I ensured that the font type is available in the trained data, still accuracy percentage is low.

Can anyone guide me if I am missing something.

Comment: I've posted an answer here that might be relevant: [stackoverflow.com/q/21827854/1679849](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21827854/1679849). Also, don't use a lossy image format like JPEG. Use PNG instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with reading 8 pt. text from an image.  Even after trying the GrayScale, Re-scaled to 400% it only helped marginally.  Tesseract OCR is just not very good at small font text.  My colleague suggested I try Google Cloud Vision at https://cloud.google.com/vision/ .  Tesseract-OCR had about a 50% accuracy but Google Vision was 100% accurate.  The have a Windows SDK at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/#windows and also have sample .NET Cloud Vision projects .  I have tried the sample projects and it works perfectly processing the text in my image which was very impressive considering Tesseract-OCR was only about 50% accurate.  The only downside is it's a paid cloud-based service but you can try it for free at least.